# Count from table with session id

Tags: php

I try to build a Notification Popup I have for this a script what seems to work
but when I add a code I am = getting the numbers 1 2 3 4 from the 4 records from this user-id

I would like to see only the total number (4)

```html
<?php 
$q=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from notice where user='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$rr=mysqli_num_rows($q);
if(!$rr)
{
echo "<h2 style='color:red'>No any notice for You !!!</h2>";
}
else
{
?>


<?php 


$i=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{

echo "<Tr>";
echo "<td>".$i."</td>";

echo "</Tr>";
$i++;
}
      ?>
      
</table>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: have you not heard of **[COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)**? that way, you don't have to fetch **everything** from your table just to get the count. which you, by the way, already use in $rr - why didn't you just output that variable?

Answer (score 0):

simply add the echo out of your loop

```
$i=1;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{

$i++;
}
echo "<Tr>";
echo "<td>".$i."</td>";

echo "</Tr>";
```

Comment: Dear Kerv, when i do this i getting all results& i want only the results from the user-id

Answer (score 0):

Just output the `$rr` variable, it contains the number of rows.

[mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

**UPDATE, example added based on your code:**

```
<?php 
$q=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from notice where user='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$rr=mysqli_num_rows($q);
if(!$rr)
{
    echo "<h2 style='color:red'>No any notice for You !!!</h2>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h2 style='color:green'>Total Notice for you: $rr</h2>";      
}
?>
```

Comment: Luca when i add the code from your link i getting all results

Comment: @JanJanMolendijk example added

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's COUNT function..

assuming your `user` table has a column named `id`.. try

```
 $q=mysqli_query($conn,"select COUNT(`id`) as USERS from notice where....
```

Doing this will result in 1 result, so remove your `while`  and just do..

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
echo $row['USERS'];
```